# Shmiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa

Tags: halacha, shabbat, contemporary-halacha, rav-shlomo-z-auerbach

The newer edition of Shmiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa seems to contain both volumes of the older edition. However, it says Chelek Aleph on it. Is there a Chelek Beis and/or whats meant to be in it?

Comment: Which edition are you talking about? There are three editions that in aware of

Comment: It doesn't have the later chapters in it about kiddush etc.

Comment: Can you please clarify the premise of the question? The new (third, 2010) edition of Volume 1 seems to cover the same material as Volume 1 of the old (second, 1979) one, ending with Chapter 41. Chapters 42-68 (from Volume 2, 1989) are not included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new edition does not contain the second volume of the older edition in it, and a second edition of the second volume was not published in the author zt"l's lifetime.

Comment: what was supposed to be in it? Will it ever be published?

Comment: see my clarification